# HowTo: Add new branch to existing fork, and then use the new branch as template to create new projects

Tags: git, github

So, I have a fork to which I wish to add a new branch to, which has just been added to the upstream.

My local forked project is (git remote -v) is:

```html
origin  https://github.com/TheoG/este.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/TheoG/este.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/este/este.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/este/este.git (push)
```

Currently I use the fork (origin) to create new projects as follows:

```html
1. Create a new repository, called NewProject, on Github (But do not clone)
2. git clone -o upstream  https://github.com/TheoG/MyProjFork.git NewProject
3. cd NewProject
4. git remote add origin https://github.com/TheoG/NewProject.git
5. git push origin master
6. npm install
```

But what I wish to do now, is basically the same as above, but using another branch, which currently does not exist in my fork, ultimately allowing me to create new projects using either:

```html
5. git push origin master Or git push (-u ?) origin newbranch
```

So, my question is, will doing:

```html
git remote add -t newbranch -f upstream https://github.com/este/este.git
git checkout newbranch
```

on my fork, then allow me to create a new project using the new branch on the fork as a template?

Comment: _My local forked project_ you mean `cloned`

Comment: @DaniSpringer Correct.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution was to:

```html
a. git fetch upstream (on the forked project)

then following process to create a new template project
2. git clone -o upstream  https://github.com/TheoG/MyProjFork.git NewProject
3. cd NewProject
4. git branch -a
5. git checkout $branch
6. git remote add origin https://github.com/TheoG/NewProject.git
7. git push -u origin $branch
```